# how to change the weight of the node to be the last one

Tags: views, drush

i created aview that list all photos orderd by weight to be draggable , when i add  new anode it take arandom weight but i want it to be the last one .
i thought to set static weight using hook_insert but without any results

```
function Misc_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == "photo_gallery_images") {

    $nid_curr = $node->nid;
    print_r($nid_curr);

    $nid = db_insert('weight_weights') // Table name no longer needs {}
    ->fields(array(
      'entity_id' => $nid_curr,
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'weight' => 20,
    ))
    ->execute();

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the function is running? Does your print_r print anything? Are you sure you shouldn't use [db_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7) ? Is `Misc` your module name or theme name?

Comment: yes print_r() -> it print the current node id and Mis is my module name

Comment: And what exactly is not working? Is it the sorting or is it the database insert query? Do you see any new row in the table  `weight_weights`?

Comment: yes i see but in another order

Comment: So the new rows does not get 20 as weight? What do they get?